# No Data Show In ListView when using in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

I'm Posting my code below. I'm not getting any view in fragment's layout even there is no error in code hope so any one can help me.

This is my Fragment Class

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(layout.caselist, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.list_client);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    adapter = new ClientListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    list = db.getAllClientList(); // I'm getting all data from database            
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Now This is my adapter class

```
public class ClientListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

List<ClientModel> myList = new ArrayList<ClientModel>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
ListView listview;


public ClientListAdapter(Context context, List<ClientModel> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
  //  this.listview=listview;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public ClientModel getItem(int position) {
    return (ClientModel) myList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ClientModel currentListData = getItem(position);

    mViewHolder.txt_client_case_no.setText(currentListData.case_no);

    return convertView;
}

private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView txt_client_case_no, tvDesc;
    ImageView ivIcon;

    public MyViewHolder(View item) {
        txt_client_case_no = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txt_client_case_no);
    }
}

}
```

I don't know where i am doing mistake and i've 20 data in my database.

Comment: i think you have to get data first in list variable then pass to adapter

Comment: are you adding your Fragment?

Comment: can you show me how to add data to list as i'm fresher to programming hope you can understand @shubham shukla

Comment: pardon @Blackbelt

Comment: @Cool look answers

Comment: Yeah Thanks Man @ShubhamShukla

Answer (score 1):

```
View view= inflater.inflate(layout.caselist, container, false);
lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.list_client);

db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
 list = db.getAllClientList(); // I'm getting all data from database 
adapter = new ClientListAdapter(getActivity(), list);           
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
return view;
```

You need to get the information before put it into adapter

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is here:

```
adapter = new ClientListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
list = db.getAllClientList(); // I'm getting all data from database
```

You pass reference with empty list to the adapter and then get new list reference which is not in your adapter. So, get your list first and then pass it to the adapter.

But I would like to recommend you using at least **CursorLoader** to load data from DB. Or wrap it using **RxAndroid**, etc. You should not access database in your UI thread.

P.S. You can read about CursorLoaders here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Yeah Problem was there. I will try to use CursorLoader Thanks For the refrence